# Star Wars: What is Rey's last name?

Tags: star-wars, names, rey

According to [Everything is a Remix: The Force Awakens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKvsc6a03Es&feature=youtu.be&t=8m54s), her last name is *Mixer*. As seen in this photo taken from [The Art of Star Wars: The Force Awakens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1419717804) [see bottom left corner] Of course, I am inclined to believe the artist was just making a joke. Are there any other references to her last name?

[image: photo taken from *The Art of Star Wars: The Force Awakens*]

Comment: .....Skywalker?

Comment: short answer: it's still a mystery at this point. This question is a duplicate of the one about Rey's family/parentage. Don't worry though; duplicates aren't a bad thing, in fact they can be a good thing. +1